Get запрос в requests отличается от запроса в браузере через ссылку
Пытаюсь получить json файл с помощью get запроса request. Но получался статус 403. Смог исправить добавить user-agent, начал выдавать код статуса 200. Но всё равно не работает. Если преобразовать в json(через метод json(), выдаёт ошибку. Если в текст(через .text), то выдаёт что-то не то. Как-то можно это исправить? Если вбить эту же ссылку в браузер, выдаёт json файл, который нужно.
headers = {'User-Agent': '…',
    'Origin': 'https://burgerkingrus.ru',
    'Referer': 'https://burgerkingrus.ru/',
    'X-Burgerking-Platform': 'web_mobile'}
g = requests.get("https://orderapp.burgerkingrus.ru/api/v1/menu/coupons?restaurant=6&is_delivery=0", headers=headers) ```


Что не то выдает, и какая ошибка?

Может быть, нет cookies?
